# How do I assign values to alphabets in excel and then find sum of word entered in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In sheet 2 or in macro code i want provide my own defined English alphabet values. When i enter a word in A2 then in B2 the sum of all alphabets should come.
Ex;-

Find the value of Eagle:

Output(Comes in respective cells of A2:B2:C2:D2):

```
Eagle-5+1+7+3+5-21-3
```

The values of Alphabets:

```
A=1
B=2
C=3
D=4
E=5
F=6
G=7
H=8
I=9
J=1
K=2
L=3
```

I tried with the formula

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:G1,{"A","B","C"})*{1,2,3})
```

But some where i am wrong, i am not getting the result i am expecting, please help me.

**Possible solution that may work:**

Create a macro which take references from sheet2 and applies the reference to word entered in sheet1 A2, A3,A4...etc.

Comment: So what would be your output? In `Sheet2` which data do you have?

Comment: In sheet 2 i have column A alphabets, column B respective numbers of alphabets. Ex: A,J,S=1,B,K,T=2,C,L,U=3  So if i enter Eagle in empty cell it gives Eagle,5+1+7+3+5,21,3. Here E value replaced by 5, A value by 1,...etc 21 is the total of all letters. 3 is total of outcome 21=2+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entered in (say) B2 will give you the sum of the lookup values for the letters in A2 (21)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET(Sheet2!B$1,MATCH(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&LEN(A2))),1),Sheet2!A$1:A$26,0)-1,0)))
```

Then this entered in (say) C2 will give the sum of the digits in B2 (3)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(B2,ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&LEN(B2))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Tom but its working only for 7 cells results only. can you modify the formula to apply for all cells of the column.A.B.C

Comment: You're right, I need to put dollars in to fix the ranges if you're going to pull the formula down

Comment: Hi tom, Now its working fine except some words plz see image link here: https://imgur.com/kJwZVzN

Comment: Some of the words in your image look a bit provocative, I'm wondering where this is going?

Comment: I copied the words from an excel downloaded from a excel macro solution forum, i have not observed the words in it. I deleted the image just now.

Comment: Hi, Can you provide me the single digit formula for column C, say if 58 came in column B as result, in column C it is 13, but i want single digit as 1+3 =4

Comment: In answer to your previous questions, you just need to make sure that all the characters you want to use are defined in the list on sheet 2 - you might want to define a space with a value of zero. Yes it would be possible to combine the two formulas - it would just mean one mighty long formula. I have other stuff to do right now but will try and have a look later.

Comment: Any way instead of combining the two formulas, we can place column B formula in column c by changing the values. Thanks for your help.Bye

Comment: @Ram You can get the sum of digits (down to a single digit) by using this formula `=MOD(B2-1,9)+1`, so slightly modifying Tom's formula you can use this combined version to get the result 3 from "Eagle" `=MOD(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$26,MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1),Sheet2!$B$1:$B$26))-1,9)+1`

Comment: That's a very smart trick, I wasn't thinking laterally enough there.